# Unable to install bower in windows

Tags: bower-install

```
I am installing bower 
npm install bower -g
For some reason I am not able to install it.
Log file can be found
```

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2ee1d6d0a46357bcc710

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I started node cmd in admin mode and solved the issue.